# Link bintray repo to jcenter

Tags: android, bintray, jcenter

This is my first time trying to use bintray and jcenter but I created an open source Android library that I published to bintray and now I am trying to link it jcenter so that others can add the dependency to their project.

I followed several examples on how to upload the project to bintray and they all say that you have the click a button "Add to Jcenter" but I such button does not appear for me.

Here is my project
https://bintray.com/tyczj359/MLCamera/mlcamera

What do I need to do to be able to add my repo to Jcenter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your repository is a `Generic` repository and not a `Maven` repository.
You need to open a `Maven` repository and upload the files to a package in this repository.
You can follow this [guide](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/BT/Central+Repositories).

Comment: Got it, I created a new Maven repo but now I get an error `Failed to send a message: Package should include sources as part of the package.` when trying to link it

Comment: Can you elaborate? which API call? when are you seeing this error?

Comment: When I click the Add to jcenter button in the bintray repo when requesting to add the repo to jcenter is when I see the error

Comment: The error is when you click `Add to Jcenter` on the Package page. In the first bullet of the guide, it says `The package must be in a public Maven repository and must contain Maven sources`, this means that you will have to include to the package above tour `-sources.jar` files.